# Socket.IO works on some computers but not others?

Tags: html, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to build an HTML5 game using Socket.IO, Express, and Node.JS. In the process of development, I've been trying to get the files on other computers locally so other people can work on different pieces. However, although all the code works on two computers flawlessly, there are a few others where Express will send the browser the index.html and CSS files, but no client/server interaction is functional (Socket.IO). The server gives the client a 400 (Bad Request) error.

I don't feel the need to post my code here, because I know it is fully functional, but I would like to know what might be going on in these specific machines that would make this not work.

Comment: are different browser used?

Comment: I don't know how we could have any idea how to help you without seeing the relevant portions of your code.  Your code is NOT fully functional.  It doesn't  work in some environments so there's either a problem with the code or the environment.

Comment: What exact line of code causes a 400 bad request error?

Comment: How is the web page loading socket.io?  Are you loading it from a CDN or from your server?  Are you sure that you have identical versions of socket.io installed on all the computers you're trying to run on?  Wild guess is that you have mismatched versions of socket.io between client and server on some computers.  If your client loads the socket.io client script from `/socket.io/socket.io.js`, then the versions will always match.

Comment: @xDrago No, Google Chrome is being used each time.